# find class of a div after wrapping (.wrap) around a div class named "root"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to wrap a div (class "root") with a div (class "parent") around it. successfully wrapped, but when try to find that "parent" class with ".hasClass" function after wrapping around class "root", It returns me 'false'. Checkout this sample code. According to me, It has to be 'true'. where is the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".root").wrap("<div class='parent'></div>");
  alert($(document).hasClass("parent"));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="root">123</div>
```

Comment: you can check like this: `alert($(".parent").length);` or `alert($(".root").parent().hasClass("parent"));`

Comment: it is actually false because document has no class parent. but when you try to add `.find('div')` you can have true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).hasClass("parent")` will check the presence of `parent` class on `document` element. It has no class named `parent` so it is returning false.

You should check for the length of jQuery object like `$('.parent').length`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".root").wrap("<div class='parent'></div>");
  alert($('.parent').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="root">123</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the script for each line description

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".root").wrap("<div class='parent'></div>");
  //alert($(document).hasClass("parent"));

  alert($(".parent").html()); //<-- Change the selector target
  alert($(".parent").length ? true : false); // get the existances
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="root">123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML that is generated:

Before:

```
<body>
    <div class='root'>123</div>
</body>
```

code:

```
$(".root").wrap("<div class='parent'></div>")
```

result:

```
<body>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='root'>123</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, it should be clear that calling `$("body").hasClass(".parent")` will be false, this is because `.hasClass` checks **if the element itself has that class, not if any elements below it has the class** - in the example above, "body" is not `<body class='parent'>` so `$("body").hasClass(".parent")` is false.

The same applies for "document" where document is above "body" - `.parent` has been added inside document/body, not to document/body.

> How do you find if .parent exists?

You can use `.find`, which returns an array, so compare with `.length>0`eg

```
if ($(document).find(".parent").length > 0)
```

or simply:

```
if ($(".parent").length > 0)
```